# Web client on WINCE 5.0 with Tomcat server

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-ce

Context:

I'm working on the design of a Project that involves a web client on Wince 5.0 and a Tomcat server ( servlet based, providing XML/JSON data). The Web client is based on C# and net Compact Framework.

Question:

To consume the web service from the C# Web client I googled and found the WSDL approach.
Being new to C# I'm trying to find out if there is an equivalent of HTTPClient class found in Java using it for GET/POST. Since the client is UI Centric I would like to have a Asynchronous Web service call to provide a better user experience.

Any links would be of great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the full framework you have the WebClient, but it doesn't exist in the Compact Framework.  That's not that big of a deal though, as you can use the HttpWebRequest in the Compact Framework, so a GET looks something like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pageUri);
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // read the response stream here
    }
}
```

And a send (POST/PUT/DELETE) looks something like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pageUri);
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```